# Problem in incrementing the filename

Tags: .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to get unique filename if specified filename already exists (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093008/way-to-get-unique-filename-if-specified-filename-already-exists-net)

Have a look at the following code:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
While System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Desktop\Sample.xls")
    counter = counter + 1
    Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}",    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newfile), counter.ToString(), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newfile))
    newfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ProcessedView.processedPath, fileName)
End While
```

If the file exists, the new file name will be `Sample(1).xls`. Up to this point, it is working fine. If the file name itself is `Sample(1).xls`, the new filename should be `Sample(2).xls`. But in this code I am getting it as `Sample(1)(2).xls`.

How to avoid this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093008/way-to-get-unique-filename-if-specified-filename-already-exists-net

Answer (score 1):

On the first pass, in this line:

```
newfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ProcessedView.processedPath, fileName)
```

`newfile` will be `sample(1).xls`. Then when you format it with

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newfile)
```

It will return `sample(1)` which is `{1}` in the format string, then in the second pass of the loop you add `({2})` which is `2`, and that makes `sample(1)(2)`.

To fix this, you need to not keep adding the (x) to the file name, like so:

```
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim origfile As String = "C:\Desktop\Sample.xls"
        Dim newfile As String = origfile
        While System.IO.File.Exists(newfile)
            counter = counter + 1
            newfile = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newfile), counter.ToString(), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newfile))
        End While

        use newfile instead of origfile
```

There was another problem in your original code in the line

```
While System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Desktop\Sample.xls")
```

Because if `C:\Desktop\Sample.xls` exists, it will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim tempBaseFile As String = "C:\Desktop\Sample.xls"
Dim newFile As String = tempBaseFile

While System.IO.File.Exists(newFile)
  counter = counter + 1
  Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempBaseFile), counter.ToString(), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newFile))
  newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ProcessedView.processedPath, fileName)
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        While System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Desktop\Sample.xls")
            counter = counter + 1
            Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}",    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Mid(newfile, 1, InStr(newfile, "(") - 1)), counter.ToString(), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newfile))
            newfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ProcessedView.processedPath, fileName)
        End While
```

the reason is because you need to get the filenamewithoutextension WITHOUT the stuff in the parenthesis `(###)`

Answer (score 0):

logic can be :

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0 
Dim testFileName as String = "Sample"
Dim searchFileName as String = testFileName
While System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Desktop\" & searchFileName & ".xls")
   counter = counter + 1
   searchFileName  = testFileName & "(" & counter & ")"
End While

Dim fileName As String = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}",           System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newfile), counter.ToString(), System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newfile))
newfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ProcessedView.processedPath, fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as well:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0

Dim newFileName As String = orginialFileName

While File.Exists(newFileName)
    counter = counter + 1
    newFileName = String.Format("{0}({1}", orginialFileName, counter.ToString())
End While
```